# Python list value intersection

Tags: python, list, graph

I have a list of uneven lengths of values now I want to convert them to a list from 1 to 100.
Thus if a list has 100 values then at location 10 will be list[10]

Now when I have a list of 248 values I want to make a line graph of this and have the x-axis ranging from 1-100% so I can ask/intersect what the value is at location 10.

Or another option could be that it is 248 values long (line graph) and you ask the value at 2.48 on the xaxis which returns a certain y-value. This is then repeated 100 times by adding 2.48 everytime for the xaxis value.

Is numpy or matplotlib capable for this? I dont need the whole explanation c.q. code. But an example or a bump in the good direction would be nice.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html is what i needed

xp = [1, 2, 3]

fp = [3, 2, 0]

np.interp(2.5, xp, fp)

1.0

Answer (score 2):

Easy! Just use [numpy.linspace](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) to generate the x-locations at which to plot the values:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

vals=np.random.random(248)
x=np.linspace(1,100,len(vals))

plt.plot(x,vals)
plt.show()
```

---

To subsample your list of values, you could use numpy "advanced" indexing:

```
vals=np.array(vals)
sample=vals[np.round(np.linspace(0,len(vals)-1,100)).astype(int)]
```

Now to find the value "at location 10" you'd simply get `sample[10]`.

---

Note that numpy arrays, like Python lists, are 0-indexed. I know you asked for indexing from 1 to 100 (and that can be done<sup>1</sup>), but working with the rest of Python and numpy will be easier if you go along with the 0-indexing convention and allow `sample` to be indexed from 0 to 99.

<sup>1</sup> `sample=np.r_[0,vals[np.round(np.linspace(0,len(vals)-1,100)).astype(int)]]`

Comment: That indeed almost does it. Now I want to know what the value is at 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9....etc...

Answer (score 0):

Not shure what you really intend to do, but Python won't normally need external modules for this:

```
class NormalizedList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        length = len(self)
        denorm_index = int ((index * length) / 100.0 + 0.5)
        return list.__getitem__(self, denorm_index)


mylist = NormalizedList(range(248))

print mylist[50]
```